# linked gradle projects: Nothing to show

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-emulator

How do I solve this problem?

in android studio
sitting>Build ,Excution, Deployment> Build Tools> Gradle

Linked Gradle projects:Nothing to show

Comment: What is your gradle version?

Comment: removing xamarin.android tag as it has nothing to do with your question

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to the programming world, especially in the Android studio, I also do not speak English, I use an interpreter to talk to you, thank you for advice.